# Elo scoring system to include doubles play

Tags: scoring-algorithm

We use an ELO rating system for a game at work and am looking for a solution to account for doubles games ($2 \times 2$), which takes into account your partner's and combined opponents' ability.

It should complement the existing 'singles' ELO system so that we end up with a ladder of ranked and scored individuals.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about the problem yourself?  What have you tried?

Comment: @N.F, I don't think that's an appropriate comment for this kind of question.

Comment: This may have some useful ideas: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15776/measuring-individual-player-effectiveness-in-2-player-per-team-sports

Comment: Also, these people seem to have some experience possibly relevant to your situation: http://www.bonziniusa.com/foosball/tournament/TournamentRankingSystem.html

Comment: So, have you had a chance to follow any of those links?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the links. The best result I have found is a mathematical explanation of TrueSkill, which is used in Xbox for individual and team ranking. It is pretty impressive and i'm testing a python implementation of it. Here is a link to the section on teams http://www.moserware.com/2010/03/computing-your-skill.html#factor-4-howd-your-team-compare

Comment: Good. Maybe if it's suitable you could write up and post an answer to your own question. That is encouraged on this website.